# Write query with multiple search functionality?

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to create a query in which 1st query will return COLUMN, based on the result of 1st query 2nd query will execute:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID from test.CORRELATION_SET
WHERE (NAME='STATUS' AND VALUE ='SUCCESS')
```

```
|OBJECT_ID|
|---------|
|A        |
|B        |
|C        |
|---------|
```

```
SELECT * FROM test.CORRELATION_SET
WHERE OBJECT_ID = ('A'|'B'|'C');
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM CORRELATION_SET WHERE OBJECT_ID in (SELECT OBJECT_ID from CORRELATION_SET WHERE (NAME='STATUS' AND VALUE ='SUCCESS') )

Comment: @DannyBeckett Thank you, Answer with my thought posted.

Answer (score 3):

Following is the query

```
SELECT * FROM CORRELATION_SET
WHERE OBJECT_ID in (
  SELECT OBJECT_ID from CORRELATION_SET
  WHERE (NAME='STATUS' AND VALUE ='SUCCESS')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't really make sense, it looks like you miss named the table in your second query.

```
SELECT * from test.CORRELATION_SET WHERE (NAME='STATUS' AND VALUE ='SUCCESS')
```

The above query would return the same results as your two queries. Assuming your second query used a table called `CORRELATION_SET2`, you could use the nested query that Kumar used in his comment. You could also use a join.

```
SELECT set2.* FROM test.CORRELATION_SET set1
    JOIN test.CORRELATION_SET2 set2 ON set2.object_id = set1.object_id
WHERE
  set1.name = 'status' and set1.value = 'success';
```

Comment: thanks Logan for you answer but just want to update you, that you can use the result of 1 query into another query by using Nested Select statments .